# Accessing the system's linen pattern?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, systemcolors

Does Lion or Mountain Lion provide systemwide access to that dark linen pattern you see everywhere these days? I need to use it in my application and would really prefer something official to my own solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[10.8 AppKit release notes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html)

> **NSColor**
>
> There's a new NSColor class method to return the lighter linen color that should be used for backgrounds of pages and revealed view areas:
>
> [`+ (NSColor *)underPageBackgroundColor;`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000353-SW19)

If this isn't quite the right color (you said "dark", this says "lighter"), you may be able to tint it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: [Use OS X linen pattern for desktop background](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165924/use_os_x_linen_pattern_for_desktop_background.html)